# Deploy a WebService from the command line or a script

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat

I have a working WebService. I can deploy and run it from eclipse on a Tomcat Server. Now i want to run it from the command line.

The problem is that when i run the Tomcat server i can't add my web service as i do on eclipse to the server.

I tried to launch the Tomcat server like this in the command line :

> tomcat

I can only add the arguments start or stop. How could i add my WebService like a do in eclipse ?

I think it could be possible with a file or something but i can't find anything that relate to my project.

Is this possible to do such a thing ?

Answer (score 0):

You put your WAR file in the `webapps` directory of the Tomcat server and run the command line `tomcat start`

Answer (score 0):

Using Apache Tomcat - Maven deploy plugin is my suggest:

http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html

From command line:

```
mvn tomcat7:deploy
```

(Tomcat 8 also use the above command)

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a war File and Place it in the `webapps` folder of your tomcat.

2) To start the server, go the bin folder and execute startup.sh

```
./startup.sh
```

3) To stop the server, go the bin folder and execute shutdown.sh

```
./shutdown.sh
```

Comment: Download a suitable Tomcat version (http://tomcat.apache.org/) and unzip it. You'll find all the folders inside.